# ARM assembly testing on Motorola XOOM

Tags: assembly, arm

I am currently learning ARM Assembly and I was wandering whether I could test the code on my Motorola Xoom besides writing Java application which includes the assembly code? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can include assembly code in a Java Application, as java bytecode is executed by the Java VM, whereas assembly is translated to machine code which is executed by the CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run your applications from "command line" so to speak. Here's a great [tutorial](http://flaviusalecu.com/post/3788777450) on how to do that. It assumes you're running Windows, but it's pretty simple to interpret for a Unix-based OS.

Comment: But that runs on my computer I assume? I meant to run it on my tablet.

Comment: No, it runs on your tablet. You manually push the file to your SD card. The output of the program will go to your computer, but it will run on the device.